# SUPABASE local development seed users table

Tags: postgresql, supabase, libsodium, supabase-database

I'm working on a SQL function to fill the auth.users table with a given number of rows for local development.
I manage to complete the creation function but I didn't find a way to handle password hash in encrypted_password column. I tried to manually register a user with, let's say `12345678` and hardcode the hash in all rows but as expected, it didn't work.
I was hoping to get a better understanding of the way supabase encrypts passwords and maybe find a way to mokcup a large number of users and still be able to login as any of them.
However, this is my scropt in case it helps:

```
BEGIN;

WITH user_values AS (
  SELECT
    uuid_generate_v4() AS id,
    uuid_generate_v4() AS instance_id,
    'authenticated' AS aud,
    'authenticated' AS role,
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()) || '@gmail.com' AS email,
    '$2a$10$nc8ek4I97q1rDN6w3jKj8uUuKGF1fMlfKaD1GNPtYDwhW6IVzA39i' AS encrypted_password,
    now() AS email_confirmed_at,
    NULL::timestamp AS invited_at,
    '' AS confirmation_token,
    NULL::timestamp AS confirmation_sent_at,
    '' AS recovery_token,
    NULL::timestamp AS recovery_sent_at,
    '' AS email_change_token_new,
    '' AS email_change,
    NULL::timestamp AS email_change_sent_at,
    NULL::timestamp AS last_sign_in_at,
    '{"provider":"email","providers":["email"]}'::jsonb AS raw_app_meta_data,
    '{}'::jsonb AS raw_user_meta_data,
    0::boolean AS is_super_admin,
    '2022-10-04 03:41:27.391146+00'::timestamp AS created_at,
    '2022-10-04 03:41:27.391146+00'::timestamp AS updated_at,
    NULL AS phone,
    NULL::timestamp AS phone_confirmed_at,
    '' AS phone_change,
    '' AS phone_change_token,
    NULL::timestamp AS phone_change_sent_at,
    '' AS email_change_token_current,
    0 AS email_change_confirm_status,
    NULL::timestamp AS banned_until,
    '' AS reauthentication_token,
    NULL::timestamp AS reauthentication_sent_at
  FROM generate_series(1, 100)
),
inserted_users AS (
INSERT INTO auth.users (
  id,
  instance_id,
  aud,
  role,
  email,
  encrypted_password,
  email_confirmed_at,
  invited_at,
  confirmation_token,
  confirmation_sent_at,
  recovery_token,
  recovery_sent_at,
  email_change_token_new,
  email_change,
  email_change_sent_at,
  last_sign_in_at,
  raw_app_meta_data,
  raw_user_meta_data,
  is_super_admin,
  created_at,
  updated_at,
  phone,
  phone_confirmed_at,
  phone_change,
  phone_change_token,
  phone_change_sent_at,
  email_change_token_current,
  email_change_confirm_status,
  banned_until,
  reauthentication_token,
  reauthentication_sent_at
)

SELECT * FROM user_values RETURNING id, instance_id
)

INSERT INTO public.user_profile (
  id,
  created_at,
  avatar_url,
  username,
  country_id
)
SELECT
  id,
  now(),
  '',
  'USUARIO' || ROW_NUMBER() OVER (),
  20
FROM inserted_users;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Hey,

If it helps, Supabase seems to use BCrypt- https://github.com/supabase/gotrue/blob/master/internal/crypto/password.go#L64

You may also wish to consider using the `createUser` function under the admin namespace - https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-admin-createuser

Hope this helps in some way - let me know if there's anything I've missed or misunderstood. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Please check my answer, I'd solve it a few weeks ago but forgot to update the trhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function generates as many users as you want for the table auth.users, given a value in:

```sql
FROM generate_series(1, 100)
```

It will create a user with email `{row}@gmail.com` and the passsword you pass to:

```sql
crypt('password123', gen_salt('bf'))
```

### Usefull for local development and testing

You can directly put the script into your `seed.sql` file if you're working locally, or run it with the SQL editor in the Supabase dashboard.

```sql
BEGIN;

WITH user_values AS (
  SELECT
    uuid_generate_v4() AS id,
    '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid AS instance_id,
    'authenticated' AS aud,
    'authenticated' AS role,
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()) || '@gmail.com' AS email,
    crypt('password123', gen_salt('bf')) AS encrypted_password,
    now() AS email_confirmed_at,
    NULL::timestamp AS invited_at,
    '' AS confirmation_token,
    NULL::timestamp AS confirmation_sent_at,
    '' AS recovery_token,
    NULL::timestamp AS recovery_sent_at,
    '' AS email_change_token_new,
    '' AS email_change,
    NULL::timestamp AS email_change_sent_at,
    now()::timestamp AS last_sign_in_at,
    '{"provider":"email","providers":["email"]}'::jsonb AS raw_app_meta_data,
    '{}'::jsonb AS raw_user_meta_data,
    0::boolean AS is_super_admin,
    '2022-10-04 03:41:27.391146+00'::timestamp AS created_at,
    '2022-10-04 03:41:27.391146+00'::timestamp AS updated_at,
    NULL AS phone,
    NULL::timestamp AS phone_confirmed_at,
    '' AS phone_change,
    '' AS phone_change_token,
    NULL::timestamp AS phone_change_sent_at,
    '' AS email_change_token_current,
    0 AS email_change_confirm_status,
    NULL::timestamp AS banned_until,
    '' AS reauthentication_token,
    NULL::timestamp AS reauthentication_sent_at
  FROM generate_series(1, 100)
),
inserted_users AS (
INSERT INTO auth.users (
  id,
  instance_id,
  aud,
  role,
  email,
  encrypted_password,
  email_confirmed_at,
  invited_at,
  confirmation_token,
  confirmation_sent_at,
  recovery_token,
  recovery_sent_at,
  email_change_token_new,
  email_change,
  email_change_sent_at,
  last_sign_in_at,
  raw_app_meta_data,
  raw_user_meta_data,
  is_super_admin,
  created_at,
  updated_at,
  phone,
  phone_confirmed_at,
  phone_change,
  phone_change_token,
  phone_change_sent_at,
  email_change_token_current,
  email_change_confirm_status,
  banned_until,
  reauthentication_token,
  reauthentication_sent_at
)

SELECT * FROM user_values RETURNING id, instance_id
)

--(OPTINAL) Here you can inser the created users into another table

-- INSERT INTO public.user_profile (
--   id,
--   created_at,
--   username
-- )
-- SELECT
--   id,
--   now(),
--   'USUARIO' || ROW_NUMBER() OVER (),
-- FROM inserted_users;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Gives me:

ERROR: syntax error at or near "COMMIT" (SQLSTATE 42601)

Answer (score 1):

```
-- create test users
INSERT INTO
    auth.users (
        instance_id,
        id,
        aud,
        role,
        email,
        encrypted_password,
        email_confirmed_at,
        recovery_sent_at,
        last_sign_in_at,
        raw_app_meta_data,
        raw_user_meta_data,
        created_at,
        updated_at,
        confirmation_token,
        email_change,
        email_change_token_new,
        recovery_token
    ) (
        select
            '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
            uuid_generate_v4 (),
            'authenticated',
            'authenticated',
            'user' || (ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()) || '@example.com',
            crypt ('password123', gen_salt ('bf')),
            current_timestamp,
            current_timestamp,
            current_timestamp,
            '{"provider":"email","providers":["email"]}',
            '{}',
            current_timestamp,
            current_timestamp,
            '',
            '',
            '',
            ''
        FROM
            generate_series(1, 10)
    );

-- test user email identities
INSERT INTO
    auth.identities (
        id,
        user_id,
        identity_data,
        provider,
        last_sign_in_at,
        created_at,
        updated_at
    ) (
        select
            uuid_generate_v4 (),
            id,
            format('{"sub":"%s","email":"%s"}', id::text, email)::jsonb,
            'email',
            current_timestamp,
            current_timestamp,
            current_timestamp
        from
            auth.users
    );
```

This creates 10 users *generate_series(1, 10)*
Same passwords for all users. You may salt it if you prefer.
Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/khattaksd/4e8f4c89f4e928a2ecaad56d4a17ecd1)